# get a matrix at the end of the loop

Tags: matlab, for-loop, matrix

How I can get all C in a matrix at the end of the loop?

```
for i=1:size(A,1)
   for j=1:size(B,1)
       if B(j,3)==A(i,3)
       C=B(j,3);
       end
   end
end
```

Comment: You could append them to a vector: `C = [C, B(j,3)];`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To collect all `C` which match your criteria, you could append them to a matrix:

```
C = [];
for i=1:size(A,1)
    for j=1:size(B,1)
        if B(j,3)==A(i,3)
            C = [C, B(j,3)];
        end
    end
 end
```

But if I understand, you want a matrix `C` containing all elements of `B(:,3)` which are also in `A(:,3)`?

**You can simply do**

```
C = B(ismember(B(:,3), A(:,3)), 3);
```

For example,

```
X = [5 9 8];
Y = [1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8];
X(ismember(X,Y))

% ans =
%    [5 8]
```

Comment: thanks, I will use the function ismember like you said :-)